# Can't use a session ejb in my managed bean cause i get a Null Pointer Exception

Tags: ejb

First of all I want to say I'm pretty new in programming with ejb and jsf, and I'm trying to complete a project started by a friend of mine.

I'm getting a **NullPointerException** caused by the invoke of the method **utenteSessionBean.CheckUtentebyId**(username) of the session bean object called utenteSessionBean, declared inside the managed bean called Neo4jMBean.

I learned that it's not necessary creating and initializing a session bean (as you must do with a normal java object) in managed bean, but it's enough declaring it.

Here is the code of the session bean, which retrieves data from a DB

```
@Stateless 
@LocalBean 
public class UtenteSessionBean {

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EnterpriseApplication2-ejbPU");

public boolean CheckUtentebyId(String username){
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Utente.findByUsername");
    query.setParameter("username", username);
    List<Utente> Res=query.getResultList();
    //completare funzione ctrl+spazio
    System.out.println("pre");
    System.out.println("pre"+Res.isEmpty());
    em.close();
    System.out.println("post");
    System.out.println("post"+Res.isEmpty());
    if(Res.size()>=1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Here's the code of the managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean 
@ViewScoped
public class Neo4jMBean {   

@EJB
private UtenteSessionBean utenteSessionBean;

static String SERVER_ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/";

public Neo4jMBean() {
}

public boolean getUser(String username) {

    return utenteSessionBean.CheckUtentebyId(username);
}
}
```

I've searched on StackOverFlow many times a solution for fixing this problem, but I haven't found something that works for me yet.

Comment: Are you using tomcat?

Comment: I'm using Netbeans 8.1 and GlassFish server 4

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it accessing the EJB Components using JNDI.
In few words, if i use an EJB in a managed bean method, i need to add the next lines of code:

```
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        SessionBeanName = (SessionBeanClass) ic.lookup("java:global/NameOfTheApplication/NameOfTheEJBpackage/NameOfTheSessionBean");
```

It must be surronded by a try-catch statement

Answer (score -1):

Create empty `beans.xml` file in  your `WEB-INF` folder to enable `CDI`

Comment: what do you mean for empty? I created an empty beans.xml file with NOTHING inside (literally nothing), but it didn't work

Comment: I checked and I have a beans.xml file in the web-inf directory. It's an hidden file. But it's not working anyway